# Getting Meeting IDs from Events in an M365 Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've been tasked with a project to get attendance information from specific types of Teams. I have a service account that is already a member of these Teams, however it is unable to access an endpoint needed to [resolve JoinWebUrls to meetingIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) (See example #3, 'Retrieve an online meeting by JoinWebUrl').

I have done the following thus far:

1. Create a new App Registration and assigning it 'OnlineMeetings.Read.All' as an Application permission (this process needs to run as a script, meaning that Delegate permissions won't work here)
2. Create a new Application Access Policy, assigned the aforementioned App Registration's App ID to it, and granted it to the service account.
3. Signed into MS Graph as the service account (using the 'password' grant_type) and retrieved the 'events' within the Team (via `/v1.0/groups/$GroupID/events`)
4. Extracted the `JoinWebURL` parameter from each of those events.

Step 5 would be to resolve the meetingID from the JoinWebURL, however when I all of the following requests fail:

- `GET /v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '$JoinWebURL'` (as the service account, which should be able to interact with the meeting)
- `GET /v1.0/users/$ServiceAccountObjectID/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '$JoinWebURL'` (as the service account to access it's own object's meetings, however this does seem to be the endpoint for Application permissions rather than Delegate permissions)
- `GET /v1.0/users/$ServiceAccountObjectID/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '$JoinWebURL'` (using the App Registration mentioned earlier, signing in with the 'client_credentials' grant_type)
- `GET /v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '$JoinWebURL'` (as the App Registration trying to access any meeting, however this does seem to be the endpoint for Delegate permissions rather than Application permissions)

Basically, I'm stuck. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I'm also considering raising a support call with Microsoft, to see if the behaviour I'm experiencing is merely a bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @NathanWindisch, Could you please confirm if Administrators has create an application access policy and grant it to a user as mentioned in permissions section?

Comment: Hi @NathanWindisch, could you please let us know that are your still facing the issue ?

Comment: Hi @Jagadeesh-MSFT, I have created the application access policy and assigned it to the appropriate users, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Events and online meetings are two different API's, you have created an event and trying to get online meeting details. That's the reason you are getting those errors. If you want to get event details please try this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).